# How to write something with a mustache in Node Js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement a website with AMP using Node Js technology, and I got a problem when I want to use an amp-list.
to write data using amp-list I need to use {{#data}} and we have the same on Node Js, so when I write the code, I don't get anything, because of Node js. is there a way to write mustache in Node Js
here is an example above

```
<div>
   <amp-list width="auto" height="660" layout="fixed-height" src="/api/v1/articles/featured" binding="no" single-item>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
         {{#posts}}
         <article>
            <a href="{{slug}}">
            Link
            </a>
            <p>{{content}}</p>
         </article>
         {{/posts}}
      </template>
   </amp-list>
</div>
```

Comment: How to write something with a mustache... 1) Don't shave your upper lip for two weeks. 2) Sit behind the computer and write something. ;-)

Comment: You can use different delimiters on server https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache#custom-delimiters so instead of `{{#posts}}` you can use `[[#posts]]`

Comment: How are you passing data into the template?  What does the route/view look like?

Comment: I think the solution is what @Molda say.